# Installing .apk works only on some phones oO

Tags: android, installation

I'm sure the problem has already been solved 100 times, but i cannot find a solution that works for me.

I have developed an application and testeed it (USB-Debugging) on a htc Sensation. Now i want to release. So I use the export WIzard of Eclipse to create the signed Apps .apk.

I deinstall the app on the htc-sensation and restart the phone.
Copy the apk to sdcard, install the app, (restart the phone just in case) and run the app. Works.

Then i grab my Samsung galaxy s3, check "unknown sources", copy apk to scdard, install (restart phone just in case).
If i want to start the app i get the Toast "App is not installed". It is listed as Installed and i can deinstall and reintall it (without an effekt on the error).

Also if i want to debug in my s3: (USB debugging is enabled, i can select it from the list in eclipse as debugging-target)

Console says:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.myapp.main.MainActivity activity launch
Uploading myapp.apk onto device '4df1fee466246ffd'
Installing myapp.apk...
Success!
```

But the app neither starts running, nor can i start it manually (same Toast message "App is not isntalled")

already tried:

of course multiple phone restarts and reinstalls
reexporting the apk

remove and reapply sd-card

install with adb install command

the s3 runns android 4.0.4, the htc 4.0.3, the app requires minimum 4.0.3.

What am i missing about this?

EDIT: 
MANIFEST:XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
        <activity 
            android:name="com.myapp.main.MainActivity" 
            android:launchMode="standard" 
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:immersive="false" android:stateNotNeeded="false" android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.myapp.main.ContentListActivity" 
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="standard" android:immersive="false" android:stateNotNeeded="false" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">

        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.myapp.main.LoadPreferencesActivity" 
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="standard" android:immersive="false" android:stateNotNeeded="false" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">

        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.myapp.main.DownloadDialogActivity" 
            android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="standard" android:stateNotNeeded="false" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:immersive="false" android:finishOnCloseSystemDialogs="true">

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post your android manifest file ?

Comment: is you app stored on external sdcard ?

Comment: the .apk file is on the sd-card, but as said, i cannot isntall it with adb either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove you Internet Permission from the Application Tag . It Declare twice . So your application declaration looks like this now:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: thank you, works. Is this an issue with 4.0.4 oder samsung? or shouldnt it be working on the sensation either^^?